# onBackPressed() not called first time from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have a series of fragments that are called in order A > B > C from user interaction. The Navigates by clicking "Launch B" from A, and "Launch C" from B.

If the user is on C, and clicks back, I need to clear an Activity level variable, so I have an interface/callback that is set. When my activity overrides onBackPressed(), the callback is called.

I am then on Fragment B, and I press back again. onBackPressed() is not called this time. Pressing it a second time does call it.

```
public interface BackOverrideCallback {
    void onBack();
}

private BackOverrideCallback mBackOverride;

private BackOverrideCallback mFragCBack = new BackOverrideCallback () {
    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        mVar = null;
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        mBackOverride = null;
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBackOverride != null) {
        mBackOverride.onBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

My API 19 emulator Logcat shows this when the back press does nothing:

```
com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb891dad0: ver 2 0
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
system_process W/AudioService: onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
```

API 27 Logcat shows this

```
? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 30719740 , only wrote 30719520
com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa59843c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa59835d0)
system_process D/AutofillManagerService: onBackKeyPressed()
```